# C.V. creation using only html/css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a Resumé for job applications now i have created a background and a small menu using CSS. Now my question:

Is there a way without using `<frame>,<iframe>,<frameset>` to make a area where I can target my links to without losing my menu.

When I was learning for ICT I got lessons in HTML/CSS and was learned to use the pages as a table and place an iframe on the right area you want it to.

Now I want to try html5/css3 to make a page working without the above.

**my HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<ul id="navigationMenu">
<li><a class="home" href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a class="about me" href="#"><span>About me</span></a></li>
<li><a class="kennis" href="#"><span>Kennis</span></a></li>
<li><a class="werkervaring" href="#"><span>Werkervaring</span></a></li>
</ul>
/body>
</html
```

**my CSS**

```
body{
background-image:url(*);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
*{
/* A universal CSS reset */
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#navigationMenu li{
list-style:none;
height:39px;
padding:2px;
width:40px;
}
#navigationMenu span{
/* Container properties */
width:0;
left:38px;
padding:0;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;

/* Text properties */
font-family:'Myriad Pro',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing:0.6px;
white-space:nowrap;
line-height:39px;

/* CSS3 Transition: */
-webkit-transition: 0.25s;

/* Future proofing (these do not work yet): */
-moz-transition: 0.25s;
transition: 0.25s;
}
#navigationMenu a{
/* The background sprite: */
background:url(*) no-repeat;

height:39px;
width:38px;
display:block;
position:relative;
}
/* General hover styles */

#navigationMenu a:hover span{ width:auto; padding:0 20px;overflow:visible; }
#navigationMenu a:hover{
text-decoration:none;

/* CSS outer glow with the box-shadow property */
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #9ddff5;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #9ddff5;
box-shadow:0 0 5px #9ddff5;
}
/* Green Button */

#navigationMenu .home { background-position:0 0;}
#navigationMenu .home:hover {   background-position:0 -39px;}
#navigationMenu .home span{
background-color:#7da315;
color:#3d4f0c;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #99bf31;
}

/* Blue Button */

#navigationMenu .about { background-position:-38px 0;}
#navigationMenu .about:hover { background-position:-38px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .about span{
background-color:#1e8bb4;
color:#223a44;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #44a8d0;
}

/* Orange Button */

#navigationMenu .werkervaring { background-position:-76px 0;}
#navigationMenu .werkervaring:hover { background-position:-76px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .werkervaring span{
background-color:#c86c1f;
color:#5a3517;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d28344;
}

/* Yellow Button */

#navigationMenu .kennis { background-position:-114px 0;}
#navigationMenu .kennis:hover{ background-position:-114px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .kennis span{
background-color:#d0a525;
color:#604e18;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d8b54b;
}

/* Purple Button */

#navigationMenu .contact { background-position:-152px 0;}
#navigationMenu .contact:hover { background-position:-152px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .contact span{
background-color:#af1e83;
color:#460f35;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d244a6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Check out [Miniport](http://html5up.net/miniport)'s source code on how to position the nav menu, within the `<nav>` div. Everything you want to do is shown there.

Specifically, what you're looking for is `position: fixed`

```
#nav
{
    background-color: #282828;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: i've tried the position: fixed then all but one of my button's where gone. an what is that Z-index?

Comment: You need to move your `<ul>` into a `<div class='nav'>` container. Z-index is what layer your element is on. For example, if I have a blue square and a green square and a red square that occupy the same space using CSS, z-index can be used to define which thing is on top. Higher number z-index is placed above lower z-index. 10000 in reference to Miniport means "on top of everything" though you could theoretically give a z-index of several million if you wished.

Comment: ok thanks the z-index is wonderfull so now i could make an area which i can target from anywhere?

Comment: Yes. On a page with CSS disabled, your nav bar will be in-line, but with CSS enabled and Miniport's CSS enabled, you can move that nav bar to the left or the right, however you want it to look, and it'll act like a docked menu without using iframes. Anything within that navbar that uses the # anchors will move the rest of your window to the proper position while keeping the navbar on the left.

Comment: okay thanks:) i know i ask alot but with what can i make like an area centered where i can show a picture of myself. the i know it is by typing: .picture{ background-image:url(...); and then the specs of the picture but i dont know how to make a picture appear with only css on the location i want it to

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        /* move these into style.css */
        .navigationTarget {
            border: 1px solid #cccccc;
            margin: 2em;
            padding: 2em;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="navigationMenu">
    <li><a class="home" href="#home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="about me" href="#about"><span>About me</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="kennis" href="#kennis"><span>Kennis</span></a></li>
    <li><a class="werkervaring" href="#wer"><span>Werkervaring</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="navigationTarget">
    <a name="home"></a> Home
</div>
<div class="navigationTarget">
    <a name="about"></a> Home
</div>
<div class="navigationTarget">
    <a name="kennis"></a> Home
</div>
<div class="navigationTarget">
    <a name="wer"></a> Home
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain what happens with the <div>?

Comment: I only added the div so I could make it big ... so it would have need to scroll.  As they say on medicine bottles, "it isn't an active ingredient."